# Python SMTP connection timeout

Tags: python, linux, smtp

I am trying to send an email using gmail SMTP, from a Ubuntu 18.04 VPS.

code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText(f"This is a test")

msg['Subject'] = "This is a test" 
msg['From'] = "myemailaddress@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "myemailadress@gmail.com"


session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.login('myemailadress@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
session.sendmail(msg['From'],msg['To'], msg.as_string())
session.quit()
print('done')
```

The code gets stuck on "session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)" for a long time, then errors with a connection timeout.
The same script works on my windows local machine.

Edit: 
after running:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

I get the same error after a long time.
A connection to IPv6 is attempted, fails, then a connection to IPv4 is attempted and fails with a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

you sure your linux machine is allowing outbound port 587 traffic?

Comment: No. Not really sure how to check/ allow either.